# PFsense dropping SSH connection

Tags: networking, router, ssh, pfsense

I recently replaced my Tomato based router with a pfSense. I have a CentOS7 VM on my LAN, which I can SSH to externally via port forwarding.

Since then, my SSH connection will drop when putting "load" on it. I'll give some examples:

- SSH tunneling to port 80... DROP (will load part of the web page)
- running a command with long output like "ls -alR /"... DROP (after a few screens of text)
- running "top" with 1 sec delay time for at least an hour... No DROP
- idle / no input at a prompt for at least an hour... No DROP

Doesn't seem to affect direct HTTP transfers (test file size 1.5GB).

I have a little experience with firewalls, but am new to pfSense. I've tried some the firewall optimization to "Conservative", and enabling "Clear invalid DF bits instead of dropping the packets". I've also disabled all the network hardware offloading options (checksum, tcp segmentation, & large receive).

It's an odd problem, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. Hoping someone here has ideas.

A little about the setup:

- pfSense 2.4.4p2
- Asus EEEbox
- Single NIC (Realtek) with VLANs for WAN & LAN
- Linksys E3000 as VLAN switch (FreshTomato-ARM)
- AT&T fiber modem passthrough to PFsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were having a pretty similar problem recently: We've been using pfsense for our website without issue for about 5 years. Suddenly, about 3 months ago, pfsense started dropping SSH connections if we were idle for more than about 5 minutes, sometimes as low as one minute. The only message SSH terminal offered was
`packet_write_wait: Connection to X.X.X.X port 22: Broken pipe`
Which wasn't so helpful.

Our MNX Solutions team eventually figured out the culprit: our state table. We were using about 80% of our connections, and according to MNX,

> We believe the issue is due to the fact that once you hit the 70% state connection limit, PFSense starts auto-tuning timeout values of idle TCP traffic and that is what probably started killing off your idle connections to the servers.

This would seem to line up pretty well with what you're describing. The more load you put on the pfsense, the more it's going to auto-tune your SSH connections and lead to them getting dropped. You can test this theory by [increasing the size of your state table](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/firewall/increasing-the-state-table-size.html). After we bumped up the size of our state table, we stopped seeing the broken pipe errors following what had previously been a month of consistent connection drops.